# Can we start an ignite node by passing ignite configurations in JSON file in case on Dot Net Core

Tags: .net-core, ignite

I am developing a project on DotNet Core , Since DotNet Core no longer supports app.config files, so is there a way where we can start an ignite node by passing ignite configurations in JSON file? If yes can you please share an example?

Answer (score 3):

.NET Core does support `app.config` files, and Ignite comes with an example that uses `app.config` on .NET Core.

Check `examples/dotnetcore` folder of the full distribution, or see on GitHub:
https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/examples/dotnetcore

If you still want JSON (like `appsettings.json` in ASP.NET Core), you can bind a configuration section to `IgniteConfiguration` object, see the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration#bind-to-an-object-graph

Comment: Thanks Pavel ! I think having app.config file in a dotnet core project seems incorrect ! Anyways I saw the example project and did try it myself,it works in a console app but with a workaround of explicitly referring to System.Configuration.Configuration which we should not be doing in dotnet core. Also when you try to test your app using xunit does not work ! Reason being, dotnet core and xunit are not designed to have app.config files !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring XML in order to configure Ignite instance. Spring config file can be provided via `Ignition.Start(string)` method and `IgniteConfiguration.SpringConfigUrl` property. Please take a look at this page: [Spring XML configuration](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/configuration#section-spring-xml)

Comment: I don't think we should advise Spring to our .NET users. Spring is incredibly complicated and confusing even to Java developers, and it makes zero sense to .NET developers.